# Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'executorWithBlock'

Tags: objective-c, bolts-framework

Honestly I'm new to Xcode and I have no idea what this means? I'm guessing it's a problem with the code being redundant. I've attempted to remove a few areas of this code but I'm still receiving errors.

Here is the code:

```
+ (instancetype)executorWithBlock: (void(^)(void(^block)(void))) block {
    return [[self alloc] initWithBlock:block];
}
```

this is the warning message:

> Conflicting parameter types in implementation of `executorWithBlock:`: `void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(void (^ _Nonnull __strong)())` vs `void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(void))`

Comment: try method signature -(instancetype)executorWithBlock:(void(^)(void(^block)())) ?

Comment: That's a really unusual block signature. What's the header file say? (The complaint here is that your header file (.h) doesn't match your implementation (.m).)

Comment: This is tagged Swift but you have posted Objective-C code.

Comment: @RobNapier So I'm trying to setup a Facebook login. I added the necessary pod files from the Facebook developer website. I get no compiler errors but I get 26 warnings (Semantic Issues). All coming from Bolts,  FBSDKCoreKit & FBSDKShareKit. Not sure what the problem is.